# The mathematical meaning of composing a quadratic equation from two linear regression equations

Tags: quadratics, linear-regression

There are alpha and beta coefficients from two linear regression equations (Equation1, Equation2). Next, the quadratic equation $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ is compiled, where:

- A = Equation1.Alpha * Equation2.Alpha
- B = (Equation1.Alpha * Equation2.Beta) + (Equation1.Beta *
  Equation2.Alpha)
- C = Equation1.Beta * Equation2.Beta

Please tell me: what is the mathematical sense in drawing up this quadratic equation?
The point of intersection of the linear regression lines is found in another way. Unfortunately, examining the values ​​of the alpha (slope) and beta (intersection) coefficients did not clarify the situation either.

Comment: If $y \approx \alpha_1 x + \beta_1$ and $z\approx \alpha_2 x + \beta_2$, it is perhaps an attempt to approximate the product $y z \approx A x^2+B x+ C$.

Comment: @Gribouillis thank you! I think so